# How to access to secrets in static site hosted in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, environment-variables, aws-sdk-js

I'm new and since I could not find relevant information in my searches I decided to ask for your advice.

I created a SPA (React) that receives a token, validates the token and if the token is valid it renders some content. That SPA is hosted in S3.

Now, I want to add some API keys (sensitive ones). Adding them to the code (manually or during the build of the bundle) it would be a bad idea, no?

I thought about storing them in AWS, like in secrets manager, and use the SDK (js) to retrieve them. But here is my doubt. I don't want neither to hardcode the AWS credentials in the code for the SDK, nor use something like cognito since the authentication would be done by this app through the token that it receives. What would be the best way to achieve this? I will appreciate advice and if you can point to some resources.

Feel free to make as many suggestions as you want. Thanks.

Comment: Does you application have a backend server, or does your SPA call services, like databases, directly? Also, are you currently using other AWS services like S3 or a database?

Comment: @F_SO_K thanks! Yes, it has a NODE microservice which handles the token generation and others (EC2) The static site or SPA is hosted in S3. So basically, the code in S3 would need to access sensitive data.

Comment: Great. How does your client authenticate with those servers? Is that what your token is used for?

Comment: For this to work, your user has to authenticate to your back-end. Then your back-end can expose an API route to provide third-party API keys to the client. Or you can proxy the third-party API requests through your back-end.